# Cleanup function runs after next component is mounted?

Tags: reactjs

I've encountered this behavior and since I'm not entirely familiar with React (actually not even close), I wanted to ask you guys if this is really the case.  Either way, this is what I've clearly noticed in my code.

Finally, is there a way to prevent this from happening ?  For example, let's say I'd like to close the current session at the cleanup function of my Main component, and subsequently, to browse the session collection when the next component gets mounted, an action which requires all sessions to be in 'closed' status.  I can't do that given the above behavior, without adding some conditions here and there to verify correct work flow.

Main component:

```
useEffect(() => {

    return async () => {
            await closeSession(localStorage.getItem("refToken"));
        }
    }; // EXECUTED SECOND
}, [])
```

next component:

```
useEffect(() => { // EXECUTED FIRST
        let isComponentMounted = true;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const sessionCheckStatus = sessionCheck(localStorage.getItem("refToken"));

            // ... rest of code

        }
        localStorage.getItem('refToken') && fetchData();
        
        return () => { isComponentMounted = false; };
    }, []);
```

This is just a snippet, not showing everything related, such as `history.push()` etc.

Comment: Instead of calling `closeSession` in the cleanup function, would it make more sense to call it right before you call `history.push()` to make sure the session has closed?

Comment: @Harkunwar I did it this way to make sure the session gets closed when the user closes the tab without actually logging out, as well.  Otherwise the last session will remain 'open' which I don't want to (I couldn't think of another way of closing it automatically).

Comment: I wasn't aware of event listeners when writing this code.  I finally replaced the cleanup function with a 'beforeunload' even listener which would be the right choice for such situations.